# How can I protect myself from revenge attacks?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm new to Clash of Clans. I attacked a village today and I did some pretty good damage. I am happy about it-- for now. I know about *revenge*, and I see it coming. How do I protect myself from the revenge? I *could* buy shields, but those are really expensive. Any alternate options?

Comment: Don't attack...

Answer (score 6):

To be clear, there's an important distinction in Clash of Clans when it comes to the amount of damage done in an attack. Resources (gold, elixir, dark elixir) are easily the most limiting aspect in the game. The most painful attacks are typically those that steal a high amount of resources. Attacks that deal a high percentage of total base damage but actually steal very little resources are typically the best possible result you could hope for as a defending player. You get a 12 or 16 hour shield, and at a very low cost to you.

Having your walls, towers, barracks, army camps, etc destroyed doesn't really cost you anything expect maybe a few trophies (and trophies are very easy to earn). So, if you're worried about attacks that destroy 70% of your base, it's not actually a big deal as long as they also don't also steal a large amount of resources that disrupts your base/troop upgrade plans.

Assuming that you can't spend all of the hours in a day every day actively playing (the game forces you off-line at some point anyway), there are a few tips you can keep in mind. The three best ways to deter revenge attacks are also the three best ways to deter costly attacks in general:

1. Upgrade your defenses

   - If your village is well defended, it will require attackers to expend a higher amount of resources in order to achieve whatever result they are hoping for (stealing resources, earning trophies, etc). The higher the cost, the more discouraged potential attackers will be to launch a dedicated raid. And don't neglect upgrading walls, either. Walls are very expensive to upgrade, especially at higher town hall levels, but are also very effective in slowing down attacks you'll typically see.
2. Don't keep more resources stored than you have to

   - Holding onto a large amount of resources entices players, particularly players that have progressed further than you have, to dedicate a full attack on your base in order to steal the resources you're storing. Have a general upgrade plan in mind, and then try to ensure that you have the minimal amount of resources at any given time to meet that plan. If you earn more resources than you can reasonably use in the near future, then you're simply collecting resources so other players can steal it.
3. Fine tune your village layout

   - There are plenty of online resources that provide base layouts. Base layouts should be designed to prioritize the defense of resource storage buildings (including your Town Hall, which now stores a good percentage of your overall resources), limiting as much as possible the amount of resources attackers steal.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: updates to Clash of Clans has rendered most of this answer out of date. Town Halls are storage buildings now and no longer grant a shield when sniped, so they should be housed within base defenses. Spells can no longer damage gold, elixir, and dark elixir storages.**

Having a shield and being online are the only two ways to stop someone for revenging you.

You can improve your chances of getting a shield by placing your town hall(TH) in a corner of your village. Some people will just snipe your TH and leave, effectively giving you a free shield.

I find I don't often get revenged unless I do something that a player might consider 'offensive'. E.g. Using lightning spells on their storage to take dark elixir. You will learn of this later.

Try not to hold on to too much resource if it's not necessary. Having a large amount of resource to steal will give more of an incentive for people to revenge.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Town Halls are now treated as resource storages, and are significant ones at that since they store a solid percentage of your overall gold, elixir AND dark elixir. Having your Town Hall destroyed no longer grants a shield, so there is absolutely zero incentive to leave the Town Hall outside of your base. Also, gold, elixir, and dark elixir storage buildings are now immune to damaging spells.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick safe way is, **Try to use most of the resources you have and get strong defending troop from clan castle**. Since buying shield is expensive it's not worth. Also as per recent update getting attacked town hall only will not give shield. And being online for more time is also not possible.